# Hiring Committee preference of academic CV structure

Tags: job-search, united-states, postdocs, cv

I am interested in applying for US math postdoctoral positions.The positions involve mainly research with light teaching duties. These applications will be assessed at departmental level by a hiring committee.

Consider the following headings:

1. Research Interests
2. Publications
3. Education
4. Awards and Honours
5. Teaching experience
6. Talks

After presenting contact information, in what order do members of a hiring committee typically prefer to view such information, and why? For instance, is the order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) preferred over, say, (1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6)?

Comment: I would start with Education and end with Publications. How you order the rest is less important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never seen an academic CV in the US that has anything other than Education at the very top. The rest of your order seems correct. I would also consider adding Service (journal reviews, committee service, etc.), Skills (technical skills, coding languages, etc.) and Professional Membership, but this may differ by field.

Comment: You mean you would prefer to see (3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6) over (1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6)? Is there any particular reason?

Comment: Exactly. The logic behind a CV is that it is supposed to list your experience/qualifications from most important to least important. Presumably, committees would care more about where you went to school and what degree you received than your research interests. I've seen plenty senior academics omit the Research Interest portion completely, because their publishing record makes it clear what their interests are.